# Adobe Flex Labels not appearing

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have these labels here and they are not appearing...at all I ran the debugged and they are being populated with text, but they just not appearing, please help.

```
<mx:VBox 
            height="1920" width="1080"
            xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:local="*" show="initModel()"
            horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">

                <mx:Grid id="floorPlansListDetail" width="1080" height="1920" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">

                    <mx:GridRow id="floorPlansDetailRow" width="1080" height="500" backgroundColor="#691a3a">

                        <mx:GridItem height="500">

                            <mx:Label id="Name" text="This is a test." fontSize="48" height="200" color="#FFFFFF" visible="true" />

                            <mx:Label id="Series" text="This is a test." fontSize="20" color="#FFFFFF" />

                            <mx:Label id="Price" text="This is a test." fontSize="30" color="#FFFFFF" />

                            <mx:Label id="ElevationA" text="This is a test." fontSize="20" color="#FFFFFF" />

                            <mx:Label id="ElevationB" text="This is a test." fontSize="20" color="#FFFFFF" />

                            <mx:Label id="Beds" text="This is a test." fontSize="20" color="#FFFFFF" />

                            <mx:Label id="Baths" text="This is a test." fontSize="20" color="#FFFFFF" />

                        </mx:GridItem>

                    </mx:GridRow>
    </mx:Grid>
</mx:VBox>
```

its sooooo weird, if I put my label outside the grid it works and displays, but not inside the grid.

Comment: Grid is a component that renders and display grid cells with a designated item renderer. Unlike HTML TABLE tag, you cannot just add random content to a cell and expect it to appear in this cell. In order to display these labels you are create a custom item renderer. Also, I don't know whether you can or can not appoint a renderer to a single cell rather than to whole grid (or a column, or a row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code runs just fine for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[

    ]]></fx:Script>
<mx:VBox
        height="1920" width="1080"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">

    <mx:Grid id="floorPlansListDetail" width="1080" height="1920" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">

        <mx:GridRow id="floorPlansDetailRow" width="1080" height="500" backgroundColor="#691a3a">

            <mx:GridItem height="500">

                <mx:Label id="Name" text="This is a test." fontSize="48" height="200" color="#FFFFFF" visible="true" />

                <mx:Label id="Series" text="This is a test." fontSize="20" color="#FFFFFF" />

                <mx:Label id="Price" text="This is a test." fontSize="30" color="#FFFFFF" />

                <mx:Label id="ElevationA" text="This is a test." fontSize="20" color="#FFFFFF" />

                <mx:Label id="ElevationB" text="This is a test." fontSize="20" color="#FFFFFF" />

                <mx:Label id="Beds" text="This is a test." fontSize="20" color="#FFFFFF" />

                <mx:Label id="Baths" text="This is a test." fontSize="20" color="#FFFFFF" />

            </mx:GridItem>

        </mx:GridRow>
    </mx:Grid>
</mx:VBox>
</s:Application>
```

Is your mx import same as above?

Comment: its sooooo weird, if I put my label outside the grid it works and displays, but not inside the grid.

Comment: I can add buttons, images, but not labels...wtf